# Eclipse e4 RCP application fails to start with "Unable to retrieve the bundle from the URI" error

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, e4

When attempted to start an Eclipse e4 RCP application that I'm developing the following error message is displayed...

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2018-05-05 14:01:24.060
!MESSAGE Unable to retrieve the bundle from the URI: bundleclass://com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.demo.DemoPart
```

I think that the problem might be caused by a plugin which isn't defined in the `feature.xml` file, however I can't figure out which plugin is missing. Using the "Show the plug-in dependency hierarchy" function under the "Dependency Analysis" section of the plugin's `MANIFEST.MF` file, I've included all of the plugin dependencies in the `feature.xml` file.

The product is based on features and is comprised of plugins which I've developed and 3rd party dependencies which are pulled in from Eclipse Orbit. The application is currently being started using the product file in Eclipse.

My questions are...

1. Is it possible to get a more verbose error message from the Eclipse RCP application which would indicate the cause of the problem?
2. Are there any other troubleshooting steps I can take to get the cause of the the problem?
3. Assuming that problem is caused by a missing plugin, is it possible to identify which plugin is actually missing?

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message.

Comment: There isn't anything in the .log file. The most recent entry in the log file was some time before I launched the application using the product file. Also tried deleting the log file but it doesn't get re-created when the application is launched. Is there an option somewhere to increase the logging level?

Comment: You could try the -consoleLog -debug flags

Comment: I've added `-consoleLog -debug flags` to the product file launch arguments. It doesn't add thing to the .log file but it does print some extra information to the console although nothing to indicate the cause of the problem. The information it prints is 
`Configuration location`, `Configuration file`, `Install location`, `Framework located`, `Framework classpath`, `Splash location`, `Debug options`, and `Time to load bundles`

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use the OSGI console to establish why the bundle can't be loaded. This requires a number of steps:

1. Add the argument `-console 5555` to the product file launch arguments
2. Connect to the console using either telnet on port 5555 or the console view in the Eclipse IDE
3. Find the bundle ID using the command `ss <xxx>` where `<xxxx>` is the name of the bundle that won't load or alternatively just use the command `ss` and find the bundle in the list
4. Run the command `diag <bundle-id>` where `<bundle-id>` is the ID obtained from the previous step. This should indicate why the bundle failed
5. If the problem is due to a missing dependency, look for one or more entries with the text `Unresolved requirement` and the missing plugins to the `feature.xml` file

It might be necessary to repeat steps 2 to 5 multiple times to find all the missing dependencies.